# Prove range$(A)$ is the space spanned by the columns of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Prove range$(A)$ is the space spanned by the columns of $A$.

Since both of these things are sets we traditionally show that both sets are a subsets of the each other. But why doesn't the following proof work?

*proof*

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$. Then range$(A)$ is the set of all vectors $Ax$, $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Furthermore $Ax$ can be written

$$Ax = x_1a_1 + \cdots x_na_n \tag{$\star$}$$

where $x_i$ are the components of the vector $x$ and $a_i$ are the columns of $A$. Since $x$ is arbitrary so are its components. Therefore the right side of $(\star)$ represents all possible linear combinations of the column vectors $a_i$. That is

$$\text{range}(A) = \{Ax: x \in \mathbb{C}^n\} = \text{span}\{a_1, \dots a_n\}$$

---

**Edit**: Note that the book I'm studying out of basically does what I do above but then includes a "conversely" statement that starts by letting some vector be in the span of the columns of $A$. That's why I think mine is wrong.

Comment: Why it doesn't work? It works.

Comment: @user296113 I should put an edit for this probably, but the book I'm studying out of basically does what I do above, then states that "conversely" let $y \in \text{span}\{a_1, \dots , a_n\}$ etc. I don't really understand why they are doing that but I am assuming that I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure but it may that the author proved the statement by double inclusion.

Comment: @user296113 yes they are, but why, if mine is faster and easier?

Comment: @Zduff You are doing the same thing as the book. You are just showing the two inclusions at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. 
$\                 $